# How do I Duplicate a SharePoint 2007 Publishing Subsite

Tags: deployment, 2007

I don't know a lot about SharePoint so pardon my terminology and please let me know what additional information is needed.

I work for a franchiser who gives each franchisee their own website. These websites are subsites of a SharePoint site. There is one subsite called Master that functions as the "template" site for the franchisees. So if a new franchisee signs up, we want to give them their own version of Master. Site Templates sounded like the right idea, but Master is a publishing site so I can't save it as a site template. How do you create duplicates (with new names) of a publishing subsite under the same root site?

Comment: This is called site provisioning and it's a fairly complex task. Without knowing almost every single detail of your solution it's very hard to advice.

Comment: Thanks @OndrejTucny. We have a process in place but it was out of date so I was trying to find if there's a more simple way. We currently export the Pages and Documents collection to disk. Then create the target site. Then run some code that creates groups and membership, creates lists from list templates, and adds features by ID. Then it reads all of the exported .Dat files and replaces all occurrences of the original site name (Master) with the new site name, then imports them. I've figured most of this out since my OP. But I thought maybe there was some way to just exp/imp w/ a new name.

Comment: There *is* export / import in SharePoint ([`stsadm` commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288191(v=office.12).aspx)). However, that may not be capable of all stuff you need, and it may not work in all cases.